# Google and Youtube websites open even when Port 443 is blocked

Tags: tcp

I want to prevent internet access to one PC retaining the file and printer sharing.

For this, in Windows Firewall, I created a rule for Outbound Connection and blocked Ports 80 and 443.

After enabling the rule, I tried accessing a few sites which i frequently visit. The browser instantly displayed a message that the my Internet is blocked and suggested me to check the firewall. It seemed to have worked.

Then I tried accessing Google.com... to my surprise, the site opened and I was even able execute
searches. When i tried to open the link to the displayed searches though, the website could not be accessed and browser again displayed the same message that the internet is blocked. But all the search results were successfully displayed.

I then tried to access Youtube.com Again to my surprise, it loaded and further more I was able to play videos without any errors.

How is that, even when the ports 80 & 443 are blocked by my firewall, Google and Youtube are still being accessed by the browser ? I tried this on all three, Chrome, IE and FireFox. Same result on Windows 7 and Windows 10 PCs.

I googled for a solution...could not fine one. But during my search I had some insight on how the sites are accessed in general and some information on DNS and TCP. Based on this I have already tried flushing the DNS cache from the OS and from the Browser. Still the same result....Google and Youtube can still be accessed.

Will someone please provide a reason and a solution for this issue ?

Comment: What exactly did you block? Blocking port 80 and 443 TCP might not be enough since Google Services often use QUIC (HTTP/3) which is (usually) port 443 UDP. Apart from that it might not be a good idea to only block port 80 and 443 for what you want to achieve. Block instead everything which is not destined for the local network.

Comment: Silly question: Are you using a proxy server?  If so, you'll need to block the proxy port(s).

Comment: Hello Steffen, I have Blocked TCP ports 80 and 443 as mentioned earlier. As per your post, I have now tried blocking UDP port 443. Google still opens. You have suggested to block everything which is not destined for Local Network..... Will you please guide me how to do this on a Window 7 as well as Window 10 PC...

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your Cache.  Websites hold data from sites you visit.  You are just seeing the "Ghost Image".  All the parts are there but they are not active links.  Clearing your Cache in your browser, closing said browser and then reopening browser should solve your issue.

Comment: Was my thinking first too, but it doesn't explain the YT playback

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem like you.
At the begin,  i tried to block the 80(TCP) and 443(TCP) and i had the same problem:
Every browser was not accessible but edge let me search and access youtube only...
I found that we can block the 80(UDP) and 443(UDP) too and it worked!
Now nothing is accessible from any browser :) Good luck!